# Salto de línea en comilla simple en array

Tags: php

Muy buenas a todos, antes de nada me gustaría advertir que no tengo ni la menor idea de programación (todavía estoy empezando), he intentado resolver este problema por mi cuenta pero ahora mismo tengo el cerebro como una pizza olvidada en el horno... os comento mi dilema

tengo esta línea de código:

```
array(
      'id' => 'loading-text',
      'type' => 'text',
      'title' => __('Loading Text' , 'pe-core'),
      'default' => 'bringing to life your design vision'
```

La cuestión es que el texto lo escribe tal cual ( bringing to life your design vision )
pero yo lo necesito de esta manera:

```
bringing to life
your design vision
```

Con un salto de línea después del "life" y el texto centrado. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Depende de donde quieras mostrarlo. Si es dentro de un textarea deberias ponerlo con `\n` de este modo: `"bringing to life\n your design vision"` (con comillas dobles mejor, por si acaso)... y si es dentro del HTML entonces usa el tag `<br>` así: `"bringing to life<br> your design vision"`.  En cuanto al texto centrado, ya supongo que te refieres a ponerlo dentro de un HTML, pero no dices que elemento será, así que edita tu pregunta incluyendo el elemento HTML (mejor todo su contexto, no solo el elemento) que debe contener ese texto para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder masterguru. Lamentablemente no puedo poner el HTML ya que se trata de un elemento en línea de wordpress y se genera automáticamente. La línea de código que he puesto antes se trata de un campo editable de la plantilla que estoy usando, básicamente estoy editando el texto por defecto para ajustarlo a mis necesidades, pero este no admite código html así que tengo que ajustarlo en el archivo php. También he probado las soluciones que me has dado pero no ha funcionado ninguna. Aun así, muchas gracias por tu ayuda